# next js website reload problems on route?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I developed website on next.js but it will be reload on route I was used pages and public folder Diffrent.

I was click on about page this page redirected directly but in my case it is reloaded so my page access time increasing so i want to find the solution

Comment: Does it only happen during production or also during dev? Where is the page hosted? Do you use any middleware? You need to post relevant code examples (```_app.js```, 
```middleware.js``` and perhaps the way you use ```<Link/>``` or the Next.js router). I suggest inspecting the network tab and check for failing request, specifically failed requests for Javascript chunks of the pages you navigated to, because if they fail, Next will "hard-navigate".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.